# Spring Requestmapping nested complex objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mapping

So I am aware that Spring automatically maps complex objects correctly when provided like:

```java
    @PostMapping("/foo")
    public String insertObject(@ModelAttribute MyComplexObject bar) {
        //do something
        return "redirect:baz";
    }
```

given that `MyComplexObject` has "mappable" attributes, for instance something similar to:

```java
public class MyComplexObject {

    private long id;
    private String name;

    public MyComplexObject(long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    // setters & getters etc
}
```

However, what if the required object in turn has other complex objects as attributes, e.g. `MyComplexObject` keeps a list of `MyOtherObject` which again could reference another one and so on.

A possible solution I found was creating a form object for the required class which translates all attributes to mappable types, but even then it'd be rather tedious and messy depending on complexity.

Every suggestion is much appreciated!

Comment: it will work out of box, complex object will be no different than simple object.

Comment: Good to know, but how would one submit a POST request using e.g. Thymeleaf in that case, would all required complex attributes have to be created first?

Comment: I did not quite understand your comment. but from client side we send a json string and https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson internally converts json to a java object.

Comment: Turns out Thymeleaf's dynamic field mapping is quite capable so that solved it, thanks for your help!